# GCS signed URL: Can I set a max file size for uploading?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Is it possible to limit the file size when using a signed URL for GCS uploads?

I read about setting a 'content-length' header in AWS. Is the header checked in GCS? Can I set a content-length bigger than the actual file size?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be possible using the `x-goog-content-length-range` extension header, at least using a [client library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/1148#issuecomment-610393302).